# How to arrange item data from MySQL database like given my example

Tags: php, mysql

how to arrange below list any way in php,

Actually we will get item array list from **MySQL Database(Select Output)**.

For example,

If We will get Array list like below

```
$item_arr = array("102","101","103","103","101","101","102","103","102");
```

The We have to arrange like below,

```
101 102 103 101 102 103 101 102 103
```

Again If Array list like below,

```
$item_arr = array("102","103","102","101","103","101","103","103","101");
```

The We have to arrange like below,

```
101 102 103 101 103 103 101 102 103
```

Again If Array list like below,

```
$item_arr = array("103","101","102","103","102","102","102","103","102");
```

The We have to arrange like below,

```
101 102 103 102 102 103 102 102 103

$rtr_item_arr = arrange_item($item_arr);
function arrange_item($results)
{
    $last_val="";
    $unique_only = array();
    $additional = array();
    foreach($results as $val):

        if(in_array($val, $unique_only)):
            $additional[] = $val;
        endif;

        if($val != $last_val  && !in_array($val,$unique_only)):
            echo $val." ";
            $unique_only[] = $val;
        endif; 
        $last_val = $val;

    endforeach;

    $additional = array_filter($additional);
    if(!empty($additional)):
        arrange_item($additional);
    endif;
}
```

How to arrange it to keep similarity On the Other hand, how to arrange nicely.

Please any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please specify the logic of your "arrangement"?

Comment: I don't think you are going to find any simple answer for this.  You basically need to answer the question @Passerby asked, and then think about how to write code to implement that logic.  If you can't simply explain your sort logic, there is no way you are going to code it.

Comment: Yea, i couldn't find any sorting pattern in your examples, this is a very weird question :)

Comment: The only pattern I see in your codes is you considering a 3 block element and sorting them and again arranging the next 3 blocks, in case within the next 3 block one element is missed out that element is not taken in consideration from the other block of element. I believe this case of sorting would be very rare case and if you want blocks of data to be arranged and iterate over the array and identify the blocks by the expected size and use `sort()` method to sort that particular block.

Comment: kinda crypto question

Comment: Item Array Value will be 9 or more than 9. Condition for Arrangement is below, No.1 Same Number won't be one after another or sequential(example: 101 101) but it can be sequential if any number will be more. No.2 arrangement will be according to ratio of every number. Please any help? @Passerby

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are repeating the pattern of 101, 102, 103 no matter what order it comes out of the database.
I don't see your SQL posted here, but you could group by the 101, 102, 103 field and count the number of instances of each then order by the 101,102,103 field and create an associative array:

```
$item_arr = array(101=>count of 101,102=>count of 102,...)
```

Then in the PHP arrange them in another array using a loop from 0 to highest count. Each time through the loop add each key to the new array if the value is > 0 and subtract 1 from the value of each of the key value pairs.

Comment: I don't give SQL because that kept in array. Item Array Value will be 9 or more than 9. Condition for Arrangement is below, No.1 Same Number won't be  one after another or sequential(example: 101 101) but it can be sequential if any number will be more. No.2 arrange ratio of every number. Please any help?